# Merge URL string in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I merge two part of strings in MVC razor view. I need to concatenate the file path and add extension ".pdf".  Below is my code:

```
<a href="http://mydomain/pdf/2021/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PDF_url)"+".pdf" target="_blank">PDF Download</a>
```

The above code throws out error and works fine if there is no +".pdf"
Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by <a href="@string.Format("http://mydomain/pdf/2021/{0}.pdf", item.PDF_url)"+".pdf" target="_blank">PDF Download